# Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack when i am changing state not pathname

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to change only state not route

```
<Link to ={{
    pathname: "/questions", 
    state: { 
        by: 'me' 
    }
   }} >
 Me
</Link>
```

to

```
 <Link to ={{
        pathname: "/questions", 
        state: { 
            by: 'others' 
        }
       }} >
     others
    </Link>
```

state is not changing and in console throwing 
`Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state value passed through Route navigation is not persisted across browser-refreshes and are also not accounted for in the URL. A better way to handle such scenarios is to make use of query params instead of state. So your url will look like `/question?by=me` or `/question?by=other`

You can pass it on like

```
<Link to ={{
    pathname: "/questions", 
    search: '?by=others'
   }} >
   others
</Link>
```

and obtain from `location` like `this.props.location.search` which you can parse using `queryString` package or similar